# Xcode: Base Localization - Running application on simulator displays latest version of Storyboard, running on device displays an older version

Tags: xcode, ipad, localization, ios-simulator

I have a problem with my app. I need to support some languages so I created the Localizable.strings file and I also have the Base localization. Everything works fine except for one curious thing.

When I run my app on a device, it displays an older version of my app but when I run the app on the simulator, it displays the latest version. I need to run the latest version on the device because I need to do some energy and memory tests with Instruments...

Also, when I build the app and save it for Ad-Hoc Distribution, I download it from our server and works like a charm (it shows the latest version).

Please, I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to clean the build folder and clean the project (Project > Clean).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Quick response. I feel so dumb; I didn't know Clean Build Folder existed :P. Everyday you learn something new.

Comment: When you're in the Product menu you have to press the option key to see clean build folder ! It's not very obvious, I think I only found it by using the help search bar in the screenshot by searching for "clean", lucky really :)

Comment: Awesome tip! Now I see a lot more options :D. Thank you.